# swapping position of two specific numbers in a text file python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

I want to swap two numbers position on each line of the text file after i replace equal symbol with this '|' and save it, but I'm having trouble to do that! For instance

123456789=123456789

i wanted it to look like this:

123453489=126756789

As you can see, I swapped 34 with 67!

This is my code:

```
with open('track.txt', 'r') as z:
 data = z.read()
 
data = data.replace('=', '|')
  
with open('track2.txt', 'w') as z:
  z.write(data)
```

Thank you very much!
Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression with capture groups, so you can copy to the replacement in a different order.

```
import re

with open('track.txt', 'r') as z:
    data = z.read()
 
data = re.sub(r'^(.{5})(.{2})(.*)=(.{2})(.{2})(.*)$', r'\1\5\3|\4\2\6', data, flags=re.MULTILINE)

with open('track2.txt', 'w') as z:
    z.write(data)
```

The `re.MULTILINE` flag makes `^` and `$` match the beginning and end of each line.

If you don't like regular expressions, you can do it with slicing and concatenation in a loop.

```
new_data = ''

for line in data.splitlines():
    fields = line[:5], line[5:7], line[7:10], line[11:13], line[13:15], line[15:]
    new_data += fields[0] + fields[4] + fields[2] + '|' + fields[3] + fields[1] + fields[5]
```

Comment: im very bad with regex, is there is another simple solution for this?

Comment: You can use slices and concatenation to do the same thing. Whether it's "simple" is a matter of opinion.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show that version.